# ArrayList incompatible types in Java

Tags: java

```
public class GPSping {
    private double pingLat;
    private double pingLon;
    private int pingTime;
}
```

**The Trip class**

```
public class Trip {
    private ArrayList<GPSping> pingList;

    public Trip() {
        pingList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Trip(ArrayList<GPSping> triplist) {
        pingList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<GPSping> getPingList() {
        return this.pingList;
    }

    public boolean addPing(GPSping p) {
        int length = pingList.size();
        int Time = pingList.get(length);
        if (p.getTime() > this.pingList[length]) {
            pinglist.add(p);
            return True;
        } else {
            return False;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a GPS ping to this trip list but only if the time of p is after the last time in this trip list. I am very new to Java and am struggling with wrapping my head around the syntax some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: boolean constants in java are lower cased. `true` and `false`.

Comment: Also your parametrized constructor does not make sens. You do not assing the parameter to class fields (presumably you will want to do it).

Comment: Lists aren't indexed with []-brackets. Use parentheses like 'pinglList.get(index)'  (in your if-statements condition)

Comment: pingList.get(length) returns an object of type GPSping and not an int.

Comment: And with this.pingList[length] you are trying to use a List like an Array, which will not work. If you want the n-th element, use this.pingList.get(n - 1).

Comment: Question title is `ArrayList incompatible types in Java` - does your editor complains somewhere about incompatible types? You should probably mention it in question (or change question title).

Comment: Hey, looking at the code you provided, I'd go through some tutorial to understand the basics, e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html, understand what api is and look into java api documentation. Also using some smart ide e.g. eclipse, could help.

Answer (score 1):

First element in `List` has index `0`, to to get the last one:

```
int Time = pingList.get(length - 1);
```

But I think, it's better to store `maxPingTime` to check it before add new `GPSping`:

```
class Trip {

    private final List<GPSping> pingList = new ArrayList<>();
    private int maxPingTime = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    public List<GPSping> getPingList() {
        return pingList.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptyList() : Collections.unmodifiableList(pingList);
    }

    public boolean addPing(GPSping p) {
        if (p.getPingTime() <= maxPingTime)
            return false;

        pingList.add(p);
        maxPingTime = p.getPingTime();
        return true;
    }
}

final class GPSping {

    private final double pingLat;
    private final double pingLon;
    private final int pingTime;

    public GPSping(double pingLat, double pingLon, int pingTime) {
        this.pingLat = pingLat;
        this.pingLon = pingLon;
        this.pingTime = pingTime;
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Pay attention on [Encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)) OOP principle: `GPSping` should be final and `pingList` should not be directly retrieved.